# Validate input from bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to make a bash script that takes user input and does some validation.

The input is small. I just need to get a user choice "yes" or "no" and a file path and make sure the input is indeed a filepath and that he entered yes or no.

How can I validate the user input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from your bash prompt type

**help read**

---

example:
 ***step 1.***

> pete@ruthie ~ $ read -p "Yes or No :"  ANSWER

Yes or No :**Yes**

> pete@ruthie ~ $ echo $ANSWER

**Yes**

***step 2.***

```
case $ANSWER in 
    Y* | y* ) echo "ANSWER is yes" ;; 
    N* | n*) echo ANSWER is no;; 
     *) echo "Unclear Response" ;; 
esac
```

ANSWER is yes

Or all on one line:

```
case $ANSWER in Y* | y* ) echo "ANSWER is yes" ;; N* | n*) echo ANSWER is no;; *) echo "Unclear Response" ;; esac
```

**ANSWER is yes**

So something vaguely like::

```
   read -p "Enter File Name :" FILE_TO_CHECK 

    if [ ! -e "$FILE_TO_CHECK" ]; then 
        echo -e "There is no file called $FILE_TO_CHECK \n please check spelling"
    else
        echo  "Congratulations found $FILE_TO_CHECK. "
         ls -lah $FILE_TO_CHECK
         read -p "Process $FILE_TO_CHECK ? Y or N : PROCEED
           case $PROCEED in
             Y* | y*)
##call function or system command to do something with this data
               foo $FILE_TO_CHECK

             ;;
            * )
             echo -e "Note $USER\n No action taken by $0 on $FILE_TO_CHECK"
             ;;
            esac

    fi
```

---

The test command is your friend. You really need to learn its ways ASAP.

`help [`

and

`help test`

The "help bashthing"  command is a great quick reminder.

see also: the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide (ABS)
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

FWIW: 
This is a very simple example and wont accommodate much in the way of unexpected user input.
I would probably call functions for each step of this as then I could conditionally represent the user with another chance.

The case tests nested like this is plain ugly :) === hard to get neat and read later

There are other ways to achieve all this try ***zenity for a GTK style GUI***.

The A.B.S is excellent but dont try to eat it all at once !